# Compare two dates based on timestamp on Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, timestamp

Am dealing with two tables `A` and `B` on Oracle 11g and trying to compare records (`A.TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP` and `B.LAST_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP`) based on timestamp on columns with datatype `DATE`

Based on what i have tried, the below query does not give the expected output and returns records even when `TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP` is less than `LAST_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP`

```
TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') 
  FROM LAST_RAN_TIME)
```

Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide some inputs on comparing Dates with timestamp on Oracle 11g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not convert with TO_CHAR.  Just compare columns directly.

The comparision is failing because you are using strings that start with the day!

```
TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP >= (SELECT LAST_TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP FROM LAST_RAN_TIME)
```